# Cannot find Error of settings.json in VS code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am still new and learning and keep getting an error in the settings.json of 'Visual Studio Code'. I cannot change color themes among other things because of it. I believe the problem is in the bottom here:

```
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../styles/"
    }
  ]
```

But nevertheless here my entire code. I keep getting a red error at the very end of the code after the last ']'. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
{
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
  "editor.autoClosingOvertype": "never",
  "editor.quickSuggestions": null,
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  /*
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
  */
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#64FFDA",
    "activityBar.activeBorder": "#64FFDA",
    "list.activeSelectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "list.inactiveSelectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "list.highlightForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#64FFDA50",
    "editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "textLink.foreground": "#64FFDA",
    "progressBar.background": "#64FFDA",
    "pickerGroup.foreground": "#64FFDA",
    "tab.activeBorder": "#64FFDA",
    "notificationLink.foreground": "#64FFDA",
    "editorWidget.resizeBorder": "#64FFDA",
    "editorWidget.border": "#64FFDA",
    "settings.modifiedItemIndicator": "#64FFDA",
    "settings.headerForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "panelTitle.activeBorder": "#64FFDA",
    "breadcrumb.activeSelectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "menu.selectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "menubar.selectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
    "editor.findMatchBorder": "#64FFDA",
    "selection.background": "#64FFDA40"
  },
  "materialTheme.accent": "Bright Teal",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Darker High Contrast",
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "michelemelluso.code-beautifier"
  },
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../styles/"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: this not a valid JSON file, as the red squiggle would show you in the tooltip. Missing `}`

Comment: You are missing a curly brace `}` at the end

Comment: Yes there was, thank you guys!